# jquery fadeIn fadeOut slideshow not loading next element

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to do jquery based slide show and I have:

for html:

```
<ul id="main_ul">
    <li><img src="images/image1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/image2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/image3.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

for css:

```
#main_ul li {
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;
list-style-type: none;
width:1000px;
height:524px;
padding: 0;
}

#main_ul {
position: relative;
width:1000px;
height:524px;
padding: 0;
}
```

for JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#main_ul li:gt(0)").hide();

      setInterval(function(){

         $("#main_ul :first-child").fadeOut().next("li").fadeIn().end().appendTo("#main_ul");
      }, 3000);
   });
```

It looks like next li element is not fadeing IN.
Do you guys have any suggestion please.

P

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

After re-reading your question I see the actual issue now. The next slide IS fading in, but it's getting bumped out of view during the fade. This is because you have two visible elements using relative positioning fading at the same time so one bumps the other until it fades out. It's more visible at smaller sizes like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bcup4/

My suggestion would be to use fadeOut's callback function. This will ensure that the fadeOut has finished before the fadeIn begins. It would be something like:

```
$("#main_ul :first-child").fadeOut( 1000, "linear" function() {
    // Put fadeIn code here
});
```

<s>$("#main_ul :first-child").fadeOut().next("li").fadeIn().end().appendTo("#main_ul");</s>

Your code is saying "find the next li within the first child within #main_ul". You should fade out that first one, append it, and then start a second line with a new selector to get the next element (which would now be the first element).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I am dealing with this code for couple of hours and seams that I know less and less. I understand my code functionality like: fade out first-child of the #main_ul (which is first li), then find next li (next child of #main_ul) and fade in. end() resets the reference and appendTo adds first li to the #main_ul. Is that correct?